# Difference between 'agm-map' and 'sebm-google-map' in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new for `Angular` 2 and I am going to create Bus tracking application so could you please help me 
  what is the difference between 'agm-map' and 'sebm-google-map' in `Angular` 2?

Many Thanks !!!

Comment: Did you try google? I'm not being sarcastic. Seems like a simple search to find out. If you can't figure it out after that then you can write a question that is more targeted given what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

agm-map is the next version of sebm-google-map.
See https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps.